# Dynamically selecting modal to open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, underscore.js

I feel like there is a super easy answer but im struggling with it. I'm using underscore and _.each to render a block of html (.datachunk and #mymodal) and iterate over an array of objects to populate data. Here is my slimmed down HTML.

```
<!--BEGIN datachunk-->
<div class="datachunk"></div> 
<!-- END datachunk-->

<!--BEGIN datachunk-->
<div class="datachunk"></div> 
<!-- END datachunk-->

<!--BEGIN datachunk-->
<div class="datachunk"></div> 
<!-- END datachunk-->


  <!--BEGIN Modal-->           
  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
  <!--END Modal-->

  <!--BEGIN Modal-->           
  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
  <!--END Modal-->

   <!--BEGIN Modal-->          
   <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
   <!--END Modal-->
```

Here is the scenario. Click on the first .datachunk and pop open the first #mymodal. Click on the second .datachunk and pop open the second #mymodal. Click on the third .datachunk and pop open the third#mymodal.  ETC...

Right now I have:

```
$(".datachunk").click(function (){ 
 $("#myModal").modal(); 
});
```

but that only pops the first modal no matter what .datachunk I click on (as expected).

How do I bind (not sure if thats the right term) each .datachunk with its corresponding modal?

I can't hardcode a specific class or id because the number of .datachunks and modals is dynamic depending on how many posts are pulled in.

**Updated****
leite you rock! My solution based of of yours:

```
$(".datachunk").each(function(index){
var datachunkIdentifier = "postInfo" + index;
 $(this).data("datachunk-class", datachunkIdentifier);
 $(".datachunk").eq(index).attr("identifier", datachunkIdentifier);
});

$(".datachunk").each(function(index){
 var datachunkIdentifier = "postInfo" + index;
  $(this).data("modal-id", datachunkIdentifier);
  $(".modal").eq(index).attr("identifier", datachunkIdentifier);
 });
```

this adds an attr called identifier to each datachunk and modal. Now I can't figure out how to call the right modal. so clicking on div.datachunk with identifier="postInfo1" pops #myModal with identifier="postInfo1"

new html:

```
<div class="datachunk borderBottom" identifier="postInfo1"></div> 

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" identifier="postInfo1"></div>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: good point, how can i increment the ID and class names with jquery or js?

Comment: It's a plausible idea to have a counter somewhere while placing them on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this on document ready

```
$(".datachunk").each(function(index){
    var modalId = "modal" + index;
    $(this).data("modal-id", modalId);
    $(".modal").eq(index).attr("id", modalId);
});
```

adds the numbers dynamically, then just follow sroes answer to show the modal.

**EDIT**

I wouldn't use an attribute to place the identifiers.

Given the code above, that places the identifier for the modal in the ID, the code that sroes gave should work. Besides, this is better than having repeating IDs in the DOM like you have now (id="myModal").

```
$(".datachunk").on("click", function(){
    var modalId = $(this).data("modal-id");
    $("#" + modalId).modal();
});
```

This should be enough to have it working if you use the code as above.

Comment: Thanks! please see my updated question. I'm having trouble calling the right modal.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like this:

```
<!--BEGIN datachunk-->
<div class="datachunk" data-modal-id="myModal1"></div> 
<!-- END datachunk-->

<!--BEGIN datachunk-->
<div class="datachunk" data-modal-id="myModal2"></div> 
<!-- END datachunk-->

<!--BEGIN datachunk-->
<div class="datachunk" data-modal-id="myModal3"></div> 
<!-- END datachunk-->


  <!--BEGIN Modal-->           
  <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
  <!--END Modal-->

  <!--BEGIN Modal-->           
  <div id="myModal2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
  <!--END Modal-->

   <!--BEGIN Modal-->          
   <div id="myModal3" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
   <!--END Modal-->
```

Then the JS:

```
$(".datachunk").click(function (){ 
 $("#" + $(this).attr('data-modal-id')).modal(); 
});
```

Comment: I dont want to hard code any classes or IDs since everything is dynamic. How can add the incremented number to the end of each class with JS or jquery?

Comment: how do I modify your code to work with a custom attribute called identifier? Please see update in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Thanks sroes and Leite!!

```
 $(".datachunk").click(function (){                         
 $("#" +$(this).attr("identifier")).modal();
 });
```